# UFT8 inside the formula?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, unicode

Is there a way I can use UFT8 (say greek chars) inside the formula?

For example I want latex to render:

```
$α$
```

as

```
$\alpha$
```

(actually the question comes from mathjax -- there You can do it, but now I need to use latex -- and I get issues with utf from pdftex).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to depend on a specific compiler, you can use the `newunicodechar` package together with `inputenc` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{α}{\alpha}

\begin{document}

$α$

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately you will have to manually declare every single unicode character that you want to use in this way. The `unixode` package does this for some common characters. I myself also compiled a [list](http://bodograumann.de/downloads/active_unicode.sty) of those characters that I came across until now.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$α$

\end{document}
```

Compile this with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The problem is that I might not be able to choose a compiler. You see I'm trying to get epub out of html in sphinx. And it uses `pdftex` -- and I can't find where it is specified.

Comment: Had to roll back your tags on the question. We don't tag questions based on the answers.

Comment: OK, I just thought it might help others in searching.

Comment: Random thought: if all else fails, you can always put a script called `pdftex` in your `~/bin` directory, and make it call `xe(la)tex` or whatnot, and make sure this is the first directory in your `$PATH`.  *Extremely* dirty hack, but in a pinch...